# Adding IFRAME to DOM by Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, download

I want to add an `iframe` to the page. This `iframe` should refer to a URL. I added the below code to page HTML, but it doesn't work:

```
document.createElement('<iframe src='http://example.com'></iframe>');
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var iframe;

iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'http://example.com/file.zip';
iframe.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/USSXF/2/

Your code doesn't work because you're passing an entire HTML string into the `createElement` function ("jQuery style" `:)`), which is invalid. The valid parameter for this function is a string representing the tag-name (like `'div'`, `'iframe'`, `'p'`, etc.).

[Read about `document.createElement` here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement)

Comment: That works. How to hide this `iframe`? (there's a big frame added to the button of page)

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the node to the DOM using `document.appendChild`

You also need to escape your inner single-quotes or use double-quotes instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.write(unescape('%3Ciframe src="//example.com/file.zip"%3E%3C/iframe%3E')
```