# Using javascript/jquery to dial a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios5, jquery-mobile, cordova

Does anyone know how I can dial a number using javascript? I've tried the following:

```
window.location.href = 'tel:7178081998';
```

The button registers a click but doesn't do anything in the ios environment.

I'm running into an issue where my "tel" links do not work because of a script that I have (FastClick). I've tried everything I can think of which is why I am at where I am.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine why any developer would think this would be a good feature to implement. You're probably going to have to stop using FastClick to get this to work.

Comment: Constructive help guys, please. I wouldn't be asking this if I hadn't tried everything else. I can't get rid of the FastClick script. I'm basically thinking that if I can use JS to do the brunt of the click event, it might sidestep the "fastclick" script. I'm open to other thoughts, let me know. Thanks for the constructive help!

Comment: this is working for me and couple of others :).. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671508/launching-ios-messenger-from-phonegap/10672417#10672417

Comment: the code above also works for me. Sounds like the problem is FastClick

Answer (score 1):

`<a href="tel:5558675309">555-867-5309</a>` This should work.

If need put a pop up dialog to ask user " Are you sure you want to call" Just in case s/he clicked it unintentionally.

`<a id="call" href="">555-867-5309</a>`

Use call id to open a dialog, on click of ok, put data dynamically to href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a sandbox issue. Why not break out of the restriction with an iframe? Dynamically add it to the DOM and have it dial the number.

[Adding IFRAME to DOM by Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319514/adding-iframe-to-dom-by-javascript)